# Ajaxterm with multiple users

Tags: javascript, ajax

With Ajaxterm (http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/), is it safe to allow multiple users to access the same "instance" of it? The program that Ajaxterm would run would do its own authentication.

Not sure if anyone here has used Ajaxterm before, however I'm posting here on the off chance that someone has experience in this area.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [serFISH](http://www.serfish.com/console/) does this publicly.

Comment: Excellent. I'm guessing this work as Ajaxterm starts a new process for the respective program ever time someone access the web page?

Comment: Are you sure serFISH only uses one instance of Ajaxmterm, and doesn't run ./ajaxterm.py multiple times?

Comment: Most sane web services are multithreaded and therefore support multiple users. serFISH supports hundreds of users, if not more, so they probably have extra ajaxterms running to support even more users. Setup a single ajaxterm instance and see for yourself whether you need more.